# Why when exporting from IgorPro All my graphics have the same size, but when exported as pdf in TeX they have different sizes?

Tags: graphics, includegraphics

Let me express my apologies, I should have figured it myself like great ladies and gentlemen here,
We use wavemetrics to graph our data in a 10 in 10 absolute  dimensions and then we export it as pdf,
Upon inclusion in the TeX in a figure with 4 subsets, using `\includegraphics` and `\raisebox` the sizes are not uniform, were have I gone wrong, it is not for all images, pretty much all rather this annotated one go fine

[image]

```
\begin{figure}
\raisebox{6.5cm}{\textbf{a}} \includegraphics[width=7cm]{image1Annotated.pdf}
\raisebox{6.5cm}{\textbf{b}} \includegraphics[width=7cm]{image2.pdf}\\
\raisebox{6.5cm}{\textbf{c}} \includegraphics[width=7cm]{image3.pdf}
\hspace{1cm}
\raisebox{6.5cm}{\textbf{d}} \includegraphics[width=7cm]{image4.pdf}\\
\raisebox{6.5cm}{\textbf{e}} \includegraphics[width=7cm]{image5.pdf}
\hspace{1cm}
\raisebox{6.5cm}{\textbf{f}} \includegraphics[width=7cm]{image6.pdf}
\\
```

Thanks a lot and apologies again, I am really helpless, much appreciated,

Best,
Sam

Importing those pdfs into TeX so that they all have the same size is the objective, have more or less done and it has functioned flawlessly even for other figures in the same document with that four arrangement

Comment: What are the absolute units that you're using?  It's a bit odd to export it as width 10, and then include it as width 7cm.  Regardless, have you tried also specifying `height=7cm` in addition to specifying the width?  (And how sure are you that your images all have the same size?  And how wide is your paper?)

Comment: Hi, thanks for reaching out cm, the very routine used in the lab manuscript preparation, paper size is  irrelevant  it is meant for screen and peer review, do printer scales it to A4 ,